# Combine rows with the same name in each column using bash

Tags: bash, bioinformatics

I have a file like the following (but with 52 columns and 4,000 rows):

```
                   1NA2  1NB2  2RA2  2RB2
Vibrionaceae       0.22  0.25  0.36  1.02
Bacillaceae        2.0   1.76  0.55  0.23
Enterobacteriaceae 0.55  0.52  2.40  1.23
Vibrionaceae       0.22  0.25  0.36  1.02
Bacillaceae        2.0   1.76  0.55  0.23
Enterobacteriaceae 0.55  0.52  2.40  1.23
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
                   1NA2  1NB2  2RA2  2RB2
Vibrionaceae       0.44  0.50  0.72  2.04
Bacillaceae        4.0   3.52  1.10  0.46
Enterobacteriaceae 1.10  1.04  4.80  2.46
```

edit: I´m sorry, I don't want to delete the remaining rows and columns. Every row name is repeated several times, so I want it to appear only 1 time with the the total in every column.
I have tried the following:

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
```

but it only does it for the first column, and I want it to work for all 52 columns.

Comment: Use `awk` if you can.

Comment: please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Have you doubled the numbers because they appear twice? Do you just want lines 5 to 4,000 deleted? Should the numbers be tripled if the name appears 3 times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With **GNU** awk and a 2D array:

```
awk 'NR==1
     NR>1{
       for(i=2; i<=NF; i++){
         a[$1][i]+=$i
       }
     }
     END{
       for(i in a){
         printf("%-19s", i)
         for(j=2; j<=NF; j++){
           printf("%.2f  ", a[i][j])
         }
         print ""
       }
     }' file
```

or as one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==1; NR>1{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++){a[$1][i]+=$i}} END{for(i in a){printf("%-19s", i); for(j in a[i]){printf("%.2f  ", a[i][j])} print ""}}' file
```

Output:

```
                   1NA2  1NB2  2RA2  2RB2
Bacillaceae        4.00  3.52  1.10  0.46  
Vibrionaceae       0.44  0.50  0.72  2.04  
Enterobacteriaceae 1.10  1.04  4.80  2.46
```

> `NR` is the line number
>
> `NF` is the number of fields in a row